# Storing and Retrieving System.Data.Dataset to Redis with ServiceStack

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am just few hour old to **Redis** and **ServiceStack.Redis** and trying to learn it.
Previously i had used ASP.NET cache where i store DataSet to cache and retrieve when required.

I am trying to accomplish same with **ServiceStack.Redis** but it is raising exception:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ServiceStack.Text.dll
```

Here is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("table1");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        DataRow rw = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        rw[0] = "samtech";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rw);

        //following line raises exception
        redisClient.Set<System.Data.DataSet>("my_ds", ds, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
    }
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? 
Can i store only custom classes to Redis not the DataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet's are extremely poor candidates for serialization which as a result are not supported by any ServiceStack library, use clean POCO models only.